# Cannot connect to Database server through mysqlworkbench

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

All of the sudden, I can't connect to the mysql service instance setup in MWB. I get this error:

> Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 with user root Unknown
>   MySQL server host 'localhost' (0)

I can start and stop the server through the MySql system preferences. I can also log into the server through the command line:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
```

Any ideas how to fix this? The following had to effect:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

"password" is currently the root user password.

Comment: Which server version / which MySQL Workbench version / which OS is that?

Comment: WB 6.3.9 Community and Mac OS 10.13.6.

Comment: And the server version? Did you upgrade the server recently? 6.3.9 is a pretty old WB version. Try the latest (currently 8.0.13).

Comment: Today the server is connecting. I'm running 8.0.13. What a flaky little program.